# Usar Python para importar informações de arquivo htm gravado localmente

Tags: python-3.x

Tenho um arquivo htm com o seguinte código:

```
<html>
<head>
</head>
<body bgcolor="#FFFFFF">
<p><strong><big><big><font face="Arial" color="#004080">Numero de Vendas</font>
</big></big></strong></p>
</p>
<table border="0" cellspacing="1" cellpadding="0" width="800">
<tr>
<th height="20" bgcolor="0087E9"><small><font face="Arial" color="#FFF500">Vendedor</font></small></th>
<th height="20" bgcolor="0087E9"><small><font face="Arial" color="#FFF500">January</font></small></th>
<th height="20" bgcolor="0087E9"><small><font face="Arial" color="#FFF500">February</font></small></th>
<th height="20" bgcolor="0087E9"><small><font face="Arial" color="#FFF500">March</font></small></th>
<th height="20" bgcolor="0087E9"><small><font face="Arial" color="#FFF500">April</font></small></th>
<th height="20" bgcolor="0087E9"><small><font face="Arial" color="#FFF500">May</font></small></th>
<th height="20" bgcolor="0087E9"><small><font face="Arial" color="#FFF500">June</font></small></th>
</tr>
<tr>
<td rowspan="1">Pedro</td>
<td rowspan="1">26</td>
<td rowspan="1">12</td>
<td rowspan="1">21</td>
<td rowspan="1">23</td>
<td rowspan="1">57</td>
<td rowspan="1">24</td>
<td rowspan="1">76</td>
</tr>
</tr>
<td rowspan="1">Joao</td>
<td rowspan="1">22</td>
<td rowspan="1">15</td>
<td rowspan="1">11</td>
<td rowspan="1">13</td>
<td rowspan="1">22</td>
<td rowspan="1">28</td>
<td rowspan="1">50</td>
</tr>
</tr>
</table>
</body>
</html>
```

Gostaria de extrair informações e gravar num arquivo txt, para ficar no seguinte formato:

Pedro 26 12 21 23 57 24 76
Joao  22 15 11 13 22 28 50

Estou usando o código abaixo mas não obtive resultado satisfatório.
Sou iniciante em programação e agradeço muito se alguém puder me ajudar.

```
import lxml.html as PARSER   
data = open('C:/Vendas/vendas.htm').read()  
root = PARSER.fromstring(data)  
for ele in root.getiterator():  
           if len(ele) < 1:  
             print(ele.text_content())
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Há muitas formas formas de extrair informações de arquivos HTM mas eu acho que é mais fácil utilizando a biblioteca [BeautifulSoup](https://pypi.org/project/BeautifulSoup/) que é própria para isso. Abaixo está o código que eu fiz.

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

soup = BeautifulSoup(data, "html.parser")
elements = soup.findAll("td")

for element in elements:

    text = element.getText()

    if not text.isnumeric() and element != elements[0]:
        print("")
    print(text, end = " ")
```

Nesse código acima eu extrai todos os elementos `<td>` utilizando o método `findAll` que retorna uma lista de elemento e depois obtive o texto de cada um deles.

Para ficar no formato que você queria eu utilizei um `print` vazio sempre que o texto não fosse numérico (com exceção do primeiro elemento) para fazer a quebra de linha, e depois eu imprimi o valor passando no parâmetro `end` uma string com um espaçamento para que o texto permanecesse na mesma linha.

Comment: Funcionou da forma que eu queria. Agradeço pela resposta rápida.